# iPad Javascript Debugging

Tags: javascript, ipad

We have a huge client-side application that doesn't work at all on an iPad and we have no idea why.

Unfortunately I don't have a book way of showing or explaining a particular piece of Javascript that doesn't work because from what we call tell, there are none.

Can any heavy Javascript users give me some clues how we can troubleshoot this?

PS - We are a Windows shop, but I would be willing to go buy a MacBook Pro to troubleshoot if need be, but I'd obviously prefer to save the 2 grand if I can.

Comment: Is it a web app? Would you be willing to share the URL? Define _"doesn't work at all"_. Do you know if it only happens on iPads, or also on other devices? Do you do heavy computation in JS, client-side?

Comment: On chrome, using the dev console, you can emulate devices using the phone icon on the upper leftmost part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Windows, but I assume you could use virtualization software to run OSX on a PC and then use the Safari remote web inspector:

https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/

It looks like there are also two tools available if that doesn't work:

https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html

http://www.telerik.com/platform#test